# Como calcular data fixa em php?

Tags: php, data

Galera, é o seguinte. Preciso que um botao seja liberado somente apos as 8 horas no domingo. Por exemplo, o cliente envia o arquivo para o site. Ele pode enviar o arquivo no domingo ou na segunda em qualquer horario. Porem ele so estara liberado para baixar no proximo domingo as 8. Ja salvo no banco a data em q ele posta. Mas nao consigo calcular a data exata para liberar. Alguem ajuda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dá para fazer usando `strtotime`, com o parâmetro `'next sunday'`, veja o exemplo:

> para gravar no banco de dados

```
// formatei no formato que utilizo no banco, e complementei com o horário fixo
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday')) . ' 08:00:00';
```

**Saída:**

```
2016-08-14 08:00:00 // próximo domingo 08h (considerando que hj é 10/08/2016)
```

> para gerar os botões

**Para checagem do status do botão:**

Criei uma função que irá checar se é para escrever o botão habilitado ou desabilitado:

```
function checaLiberacao($dt_liberacao) {
    $liberado = strtotime($dt_liberacao);
    $agora = strtotime('now');
    if ($liberado <= $agora) {
        echo '';
    } else {
        echo 'botão desabilitado';
    }
}
```

**USO:**

```
$dt_liberacao = '2016-08-14 08:00:00'; // substituir por método para trazer dados do banco
checaLiberacao($dt_liberacao);
```

> Retorna: botão desabilitado

Outro exemplo:

```
$dt_liberacao = '2016-08-09 08:00:00'; // substituir por método para trazer dados do banco
checaLiberacao($dt_liberacao);
```

Retorna:

> botão habilitado

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: +1 Mas podia dar jeito inserir a comparação também: Botão enable/disable. Para ficar mais completo

Comment: Feito, é só substituir a data fixa pela que você trouxer do banco de dados e implementar o método para gerar os botões.

Comment: Vlw, resolveu meu problema!